# Best practice to deploy business network across organizations

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Using Composer Playground I can deploy my business network to the peers listed in the connection profile.  My understanding is that the connection profile is only able to talk to a single organization that corresponds the MSPID listed in the profile.

To create a meaningful blockchain application though I have to be able to deploy chaincode cross organization hence I need to be able to deploy the same business network I created in composer across organization.

What is the suggested way to do this?   I think the way to do it is by creating a connection profile per organization and deploy the same .bna file on each of the organizations.    What I wonder from that approach is whether the business network (and implicitly the chaincode) deployed by each connection profile are recognized as the same across organizations.  How are these business networks deployed across different organizations related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the latest version of Composer (v0.16.2) we are generally separating the Deploy into `composer runtime install` and `composer network start`.

The runtime install needs to be run Once per Org, assuming that a connection profile (under a Card) lists all the Peers in that Org.

After the Runtime is installed, the Network Start command can be run just once for the Network and this will then be started on all the peers in both organisations.

If you haven't already seen it, this Tutorial Document gives some insight on the task, though be aware that it is an illustration of some of the Composer aspects, but it runs a Multi Org on a single machine:
[Deploying to a Multi-Org Network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that it is supported in the command line but Composer Playground has not been updated yet.

Comment: I don't think Composer supports deploying Networks to Multi-org Fabrics.  However once it has been set up you can use Composer to interact with it.